# Workflow rule for 180 days

Tags: workflow

I want to send an email after 180 days. Requirement is like application status is started and it is in idle stage for 180 days then only email should get sent.

So how can i achieve this using workflow

Comment: You've received a great answer, but next time, please make sure to look at [ask] and include in your post *what you've tried* and *where you're stuck*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  [time-depended workflow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_time_dependent.htm&type=5). It is possible to create time-depended action only if Evaluation Criteria doesn't equal `created, and every time it's edited`.
[image]

Save in a new field on your record date, when application status is started and create time-depended action `180 Days After DATE_FIELD`

[image]

---

I'd recommend using process builder and scheduled action if this is new automation, that you are implementing because [Say Goodbye to Workflow and Hello to Process Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/workflow_migration/workflow_migration_intro)

[Considerations for Scheduling Process Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled.htm&type=5)

Comment: Is there any specific evaluation criteria